# Send child class's property with parent class's property in ResponseEntity in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, inheritance, json-deserialization

Considering a Multi level inheritance scenario among ParentInterface -> ParentClass -> ChildClass POJOs. I need to use return type as Interface in my `ResponseEntity<ParentInterface>` Controller's `GET` call. Now, as per some logic, I need to either set the object of ParentClass or ChildClass in the Interface variable. But the response always contains the `parentClassProperty`.

**Parent Interface**

```
interface ParentInterface {
  String parentClassProperty;
}
```

**Parent Class**

```
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@JsonInclude
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ParentClass.ParentClassBuilder.class)
class ParentClass implements ParentInterface {
String parentClassProperty;

  @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public static class ParentClassBuilder {
    String parentClassProperty;

    public ParentClassBuilder() {}

    @Override
    public ParentClassBuilder parentClassProperty(String parentClassProperty) {
      this.parentClassProperty = parentClassProperty;
      return this;
    }

    public ParentClass build() {
      return new ParentClass(parentClassProperty);
    }
  }
}
```

**Child Class**

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@JsonInclude
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ChildClass.ChildClassBuilder.class)
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
String childClassProperty;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class ChildClassBuilder extends ParentClassBuilder {
      String childClassProperty;

      public ChildClassBuilder() {}

      public ChildClassBuilder childClassProperty(String childClassProperty) {
        this.childClassProperty = childClassProperty;
        return this;
      }

      @Override
      public ChildClassBuilder parentClassProperty(String parentClassProperty) {
       this.parentClassProperty = parentClassProperty;
       return this;
      }

      public ChildClass build() {
        return new ChildClass(parentClassProperty, childClassProperty);
      }
    }
  }
```

Controller

```
public ResponseEntity<ParentInterface> getValues() {
  ParentInterface parentInterface;
  ParentClass parentClass = getParentClassValuesFromSomeMethod();  
  if (some_boolean == true) {
    parentInterface = parentClass;
  }
  else {
    ChildClass childClass = getChildClassValuesFromSomeMethod();  
    parentInterface = childClass;
  }
  return parentInterface;
}
```

Now, above method always returns `parentClassProperty` but what I need is to have both `childClassProperty` and `parentClassProperty`. I know that problem is somewhere in the JSONDeserialization but unable to figure it out as where I am making the mistake.